# C# read json data from url without using api

Tags: c#, json, api, yammer

We are getting yammer data using yammer api however in our scenario we want a notification data but there is no api support for that, as an alternative we thought of reading the json content from a url, when we type this url in browser "https://www.yammer.com/******/notifications.json" we are getting data in the browser however through C# we are getting 406 error as there is no api support.

For api we use token id as oauth authenticating medium but to get content from a url in the form of json what authentication is available, in short please help with some code

Code we have used:

```
                HttpWebRequest Request = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest; 
                Request.Method = "GET";               
                Request.ContentType = "application/json; odata=verbose";       
                Request.Accept = "application/json; odata=verbose";                
                string Token = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Token"];            
                Request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, Token);            

                var wResp = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
```

If you have any alternative solution please help.

Comment: sniff the browser request and request send by your app, just my speculation  but seems like your `Token` has issues

Comment: I don't see any issues with Token as it works for defined api's.

Comment: best way to use a sniffer and see the differences between your app request and request send by the browser, as your issue cannot be reproduced *(/******/notifications.json)* - that all I can help you with ...

Comment: well this is not a rest api(/******/notifications.json) so that's the problem for my app, I need a way to read the browser content using some authentication medium.

Comment: if there is a way to get Json via Browser - then you for sure can download it, tricky part is authentication as I understand ....

Comment: Anyone who can help on this?